# php and ajax passing form value

Tags: php, ajax

Hi how would I echo the form input "date" in a PHP file from the code below. (`data: "name=Peter&location=Sheffield" + $('input[name="date"]').val(),`)

at the moment I have `echo "todays date ".$_POST['date']."<br>";` but it doesnt seem to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js>    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// This functions starts the ajax to show the output from post.php
function StartAjax(ResultsId){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "postTest.php",
      cache: false,
      data: "name=Peter&location=Sheffield" + $('input[name="date"]').val(),
      success: function(html, status){
        $("#"+ResultsId).append(html);
        $('#status').append(status);
      } 
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Run Club</h1>
testing
<form>
date: <input type="text" name="date"><br>
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="StartAjax('ResultsId');">Click Here to see updates from postTest.php</a>
<div id="ResultsId"></div>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a date key in your query string

```
data: "name=Peter&location=Sheffield&date=" + $('input[name="date"]').val(),
```

alternatively you should pass an object to data so jQuery will format the query string for you.

```
data: {name: "Peter", location: "Sheffield", date: $('input[name="date"]').val()},
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function StartAjax(ResultsId){
var date = document.getElementsByName("date").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "postTest.php",
      cache: false,
      data: "name=Peter&location=Sheffield&date=" + date,
      success: function(html, status){
        $("#"+ResultsId).append(html);
        $('#status').append(status);
      } 
    });
}
```